# Cannot fill variables of an Array of structures with a .txt file in VB2010

Tags: arrays, vb.net, data-structures

This is just the first form of this project which I have canned and rebuilt from scratch countless times. I am at my wit's end and just can't seem to get the program to run without errors. I'm using the split method to designate data in the array to name and ID# variables in a structure so I can search through them later with another algorithm 
You can see the array actually is getting populated with the contents of the .txt file in the second image screenshot....
(It's super transparent due to having to hit cntrl to take a screenshot)

However, I keep getting NUll.reference exceptions or some crap like that
HELP!!!!!

...Great it won't let me put pics because I'm new....wonderful

```
Public Class Form1

    Structure records
        Dim fullName As String
        Dim stuID As String
    End Structure

    Dim stuRec() As records

    'Enables the last name text box
    Private Sub txtfname_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtfname.TextChanged

        txtlname.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    'Enables the student ID text box
    Private Sub txtlname_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtlname.TextChanged

        txtstuID.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    'Enables the submit button
    Private Sub txtstuID_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtstuID.Enter

        btnSub.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    'Displays an error message when invalid data is entered into the student id masked text box
    Private Sub txtstuID_MaskInputRejected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles txtstuID.MaskInputRejected

        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Last 7 Digits of your Student ID", "Invalid Input")
    End Sub

    'This loads the 1-dimension array stuRec() of the structure records with the data in the text file stuID.txt
    'While setting the data to fullName or stuID variables using the line.Split method
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim records() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("stuID.txt")

        For i As Integer = 0 To records.Count - 1
            Dim data() As String = records(i).Split(","c)
            stuRec(i).fullName = data(0)   ...Here's where the problem is...
            stuRec(i).stuID = data(1)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSub_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSub.Click

        Dim fname As String = CStr(txtfname.Text)
        Dim lname As String = CStr(txtlname.Text)
        Dim fullName As String = (fname & " " & lname)

        ‘(The Search code will go here)
    End Sub
```

> Blockquote

I have no idea why intelisense insists on using this function…it added it itself to resolve the issue I had but, it did not fix the problem

```
    Private Function data(ByVal p1 As Integer) As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Doesn't look like `stuRec` was ever instantiated or initialized.

Comment: No, NOT "some crap like that".  Something specific happens so tell us that, EXACTLY.  If it's a NullReferenceException then WHERE is it thrown and what reference is Nothing on that line when it's thrown?

Comment: Visual Studio created Function data() for you because at some point you clicked the red X and choose to create the function - VS was underlining data at that point. Your code is now calling data, which then throws an exception, just remove the function completely and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Structure records
        Dim fullName As String
        Dim stuID As String
    End Structure

    Dim stuRec() As records
```

The stuRec Array has an undefined length, I would recommend using a List(of records).

```
Dim stuRec as New List(of records)
```

To add an entry to the List:

```
stuRec.Add(New records with {.fullName = data(0), .stuID = data(1)})
```

Even better would be if make a check if data has for ex. a length of 2 before adding so you don't get another exception if some data is missing

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly, I initialized the array of structures to Dim stuRec() As List(Of records)... (Intelisense wouldn't allow me to declare an array using the "New" syntax) I still have errors   for stuID and fullName not being a member of System.Collection.Generic.List(Of stuRegis.Form1.records)   I have to be able to read and write to the files scanned in